# Error importing Tensorflow when import tensorflow as tf

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, installation

I've recently gone through the installation of tensorflow (and struggled a little) and when I believed I had got it, I now get these import errors when running a file that ONLY contains `import tensorflow as tf`, I ran the cmd: `python3 tftest.py` and get these import errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: invalid ELF header

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stockprice.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: invalid ELF header


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

I do have tensorflow installed

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 0.12.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requires: numpy, six, protobuf, wheel
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, has anyone encountered this or a similar error? I've looked at installation manuals, and followed every single step I could. I've tried reintalling protobuf

I am not running my test file on the tensorflow directory.

I would really REALLY appreciate any help since this error is draining my brain out.

Comment: Did you build from source? it can get messy, I would suggest using conda for a clean easy install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the library file manually and reinstall it using pip

Comment: Woah, that worked..i guess throughout my installation i must've messed up stuff. I went to the tensorflow folder and `/bin/rm -r` all the tensorflow folders, reinstalled using `pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow` and now ran the code with no import errors, and hopefully can now use tensorflow properly

Comment: It happens if you previously installed some other packages that messes up with tensorflow. Don't know why this happens

Answer (score 0):

check through `pip list` not to have installed the `tensorflow-gpu` library because some GPUs are not supported.

If this is the case, ***uninstall tensor flow-gpu*** and ***tensorflow-estimator*** and ***re-install tensorflow*** :
`pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu`
 
`pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator`
 
`pip install tensorflow`
 
make sure you use python 3.6 with the `pip -V` command

Answer (score 0):

What I did was clicking

Runtime -> Restart Runtime

and running the code all over again, it worked like magic.