# Tensorflow ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

I've seen that a lot of questions have already asked this, but it seems to be very specific as none of the answers seem to work.

Let me explain the steps that I have taken to install everything:

I started with installing Python 3.7.4 and installed tensorflow after that. The command I ran is: `pip install -q tensorflow=2.0.0-alpha0`. This didn't seem to work and I soon figured out that this is because of the version of Python. Tensorflow doesn't support 3.7 yet, so I installed Python 3.6.0.

I then installed tensorflow again with the following command: `pip3.6 install tensorflow`. Note the explicit `pip3.6`. I then select python 3.6 in the configuration of Visual Code's Python Debugger. I ran the following code (single line) and gave me the following error:

**Python**

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

After some searching, [someone said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245982/4000771) that uninstalling tensorflow-estimator and tensorflow-gpu may work, because of unsupported gpu's. Even though I doubted this since I have an RTX 2080, I decided to give it a go, but I still got the same result.

I'm hoping any of you would be able to help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

After installing Anaconda and using conda to install my packages with (instead of pip) this issue has been resolved. However, a nice issue occurs. With the someline of code I get the following error (pretty much the same as the last one, but a different package module):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.conda\envs\Python 3.6\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.conda\envs\Python 3.6\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.conda\envs\Python 3.6\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\Documents\Projects\Python_Neural_Networks\Tutorial_1\Tutorial_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.conda\envs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.conda\envs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.conda\envs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Meine Zeinstra\.conda\envs\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I hope you can help me with this new issue.

Comment: Try reinstalling *protobuf*.

Comment: @CristiFati Reinstalling `protobuf` doesn't seem to fix any issues.

Comment: I had the same problem, I installed Tensorflow with conda: `conda install tensorflow`. After that it worked, conda sometimes has a better placement of the files.

Comment: @marcuse (Ana)conda is only for 3.7 python or 2.7 python.. Can I specify the python version, or install location later as well? Since I need python 3.6 to run tensorflow.

Comment: @marcuse Okay, conda indeed solves this issue, however... I get a new issue.. I'll update my post with this information.

Comment: Are you using PyCharm?

Comment: @marcuse No, I'm using VS Code. Could that be an issue?

Comment: It should work in PyCharm by now. But found a similair error output of another VS Code user with anaconda: check [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10884#issuecomment-508684847)

Comment: Can you please try with following commands  pip install tensorflow==2.0                     please try answers from following similar issues.                  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090359/tensorflow-gpu-installation-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-c                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727917/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-while-att